# How can I recieve messages from Web Workers when they have the same name?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am currently learning Web Workers in JavaScript, and therefore, making a script says something 8 times, every thread does 1.

So to make it, I use this code:

main.js

```
for (let workersAmount = 0; workersAmount < 4; workersAmount++)
{
    var socketWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
}

socketWorker.onmessage = function(event)
{
    console.log(event.data);
}
```

worker.js:

```
postMessage("Why can't it just work!")
```

And this is the result (this is my first post here so I can't embed):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwY66.png)

As you can see, it only shows the text 1 time, while there are 4 workers. Which (I think) is because is replace the variable "socketWorker" everytime, but still keeps the old worker.js

So, does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't have the same name. They don't have *names* at all.

The `socketWorker` variable has a name. It also has a value.

First it has the value that is a reference to the first worker. Then you immediately overwrite it with the value that is a reference the second worker. And so on.

When you overwrite the first reference you **no longer have that reference**.

You have thrown it away.

You can't get it back.

By the time you get to the line `socketWorker.onmessage = function(event)`, you've only got the **last** reference you stored in `socketWorker` available to you.

---

Assign a value to the `onmessage` property **inside** the `for` loop, **before** you overwrite the value of `socketWorker`.

If you need to keep a reference to each of your workers around for the future, then `push` them into an array instead of using a single variable which you keep overwriting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you provide some code,  since I'm still pretty new to JavaScript?

Comment: @Hoiboy19 — "Assign a value to the onmessage property" is something you are already doing. "inside the for loop" is where you should be doing it. Just move it.

Comment: Thanks! I moved socketWorker.onmessage into the for loop and it's working now!